# ¿Cómo puedo poner una fechas mínimas en el datetimepicker()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap

Tengo un input al cual le tengo asignado un datetimepicker() para que este pueda mostrar fechas.

```
$('.fecha').datetimepicker({ 'locale': 'es'});
```

quisiera saber si existe alguna opción del datetimepicker al cual me permite poner como fecha mínima a elegir 1 mes anterior al actual, es decir, si estamos a febrero pues me permite elegir las fechas de enero pero no las de diciembre, ni fechas anteriores a diciembre

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El metodo es `minDate` para poner la fecha minima. Ahora con lo que dices "1 mes anterior", se puede hacer con `moment().subtract(1, 'months')`, quedaria asi:

```
$('.fecha').datetimepicker({ 
    'locale': 'es',
    'minDate': moment().subtract(1, 'months')
});
```

**Referencias**

- https://momentjs.com/
- https://getdatepicker.com/4/Options/

Comment: Gracias, si me resultó.

Answer (score 1):

Intenta con esto:

```
var f = new Date();//Sirve de auxiliar para pasar parámeros al minDate 

$('.fecha').datetimepicker({ 
 'locale': 'es',
 'yearRange': '2020:'+f.getFullYear(),
 'minDate': new Date(f.getFullYear(), f.getMonth() -1, 1)

});
```

Obtiene el mes y se le resta uno para el mes anterior, y desde el día 1.